# Menu Bug in IE 7 - W

Tags: html, css, debugging, internet-explorer-7

Does any one know how I can fix [this menu](http://glamourunderground.com) in IE7-W? It also doesn't work in Firefox 3 and other old browsers... Do I need to bother fixing it for old browsers..?

Thank you,

Tara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra html open and closing tags in the document that appear to be messing things up -- they wrap around your "rightcol" div

Remove those  and see if things get fixed.

```
<html>   <!-- REMOVE THIS LINE   -->
<div id="rightcol">

    ... [inner content]

</div>
</html>  <!-- AND REMOVE THIS LINE TOO   -->
```